# Deserialization: get the data from the custom class

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to get the `route, direction, longitude and latitude` which I am getting from web services. I have craeted MapDataJSON class to deserilaize the json string with 'Gson' libraray but I dont know how to get the data from the MapDataJSON object. How can I get the data `route, direction, latitude and longitude` from MapDataJSSON class?

I appreciate any help.

**Json string**

```
[
  {
    "latitude": 20.123456,
    "longitude": 70.123456,
    "route": 4,
    "direction": "ABC"
   },

   {
    "latitude": 30.123456,
    "longitude": 80.123456,
    "route": 9,
    "direction": "DEF"
   },
     {
    "latitude": 10.123456,
    "longitude": 90.123456,
    "route": 3,
    "direction": "GHI"
   }

]
```

**Code:**

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MapDataJSON[] data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(),
                MapDataJSON[].class);
```

**MapDataJSON class:**

```
package com.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapDataJSON {
    ArrayList<ItemDTO> items;

    public MapDataJSON(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDTO> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public static class ItemDTO {
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        int route;
        String direction;

        public ItemDTO(double latitude, double longitude, int route,
                String direction) {
            super();
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.route = route;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public int getRoute() {
            return route;
        }

        public String getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public void setRoute(int route) {
            this.route = route;
        }

        public void setDirection(String direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `for (ItemDTO item : data.getItems())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code to block below. You dont need `MapDataJSON` for wrapping item.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {}.getType();
List<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(json, listType);

for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {
    System.out.print(itemDTO.getLatitude());
}
```